# Solving $e^z = 1 $ in complex plane

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

I am solving the equation $e^z = 1 $ in $\mathbb{C}$. The book says, other than $z = 0$, $z = 2 \pi k i$ for $ k \in \mathbb{Z}$ is also the solution. It explains the solution by saying that $e^z$ is periodic function so that

$1 = e^z = e^{2\pi k i}$

However I want to know how the identity is derived to solve other cases such as $e^z = 2 $.

Comment: "However I want to know how the identity is derived " - which identity? You mean that $\ker(\exp)=2\pi i\Bbb Z$?

Comment: Do you know how exponential works? The formula is $e^{x+iy}=e^x(\cos(y)+i\sin(y))$. And now we just have to use the fact that two non zero complex numbers are equal if and only if they have the same absolute value and same argument up to an integer multiple of $2\pi$.

Answer (score 1):

There is a change in the modulus only. If $z=x+iy$, 
 $e^z=e^xe^{i\theta}=1$ and in the second case
$e^z=e^xe^{i\theta}=2.$  You can observe that  no change in the arguments. That is why 
In the first case $e^x=1; x=\ln 1=0, y=2k\pi$ and in the second case $e^x=2; x=\ln 2, y=2k\pi.$  Note that $|e^z|=e^x$

Answer (score 0):

Note

$$e^z=2=e^{\ln2+2\pi ki}$$

which leads to the solutions

$$z = \ln 2+2\pi ki$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $z=x+iy$ where $x, y$ are real.  Then $e^z = 2$ means
$$
e^x\cos y + i e^x\sin y = 2,
\\
e^x\cos y = 2\quad\text{and}\quad e^x\sin y = 0
$$
Now $e^x \ne 0$ for all $x$, so from $e^x\sin y = 0$ we get $\sin y = 0$, and thus
$y = n\pi$ for some $ n \in \mathbb Z$.  From this we get $\cos y = \cos(n\pi) = (-1)^n$.  But $e^x > 0$ for all $x$, so we must have $n$ even, say $n=2k$.  Finally,
$2 = e^x\cos y = e^x\cos(2k\pi)= e^x$, so $x=\ln 2$.  Conclusion: $z = \ln 2 + i2k\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the fact that $e^a = e^b$ if and only if $b-a = 2\pi ki$ for some integer $k$.

So as long as you can find *some* value of $z$ with $e^z=2$, this lets you find *all* such values.

For this example, you certainly know that $2 = e^{\ln 2}$ (where "$\ln$" is the ordinary real-valued function of a positive real variable), so
$$2 = e^z\tag{given equation to solve}$$
$$\iff e^{\ln 2} = e^z\tag{because $2=e^{\ln 2}$}$$
$$\iff z - \ln 2 = 2\pi ki\tag{rule I cited}$$
$$\iff z = \ln 2 + 2\pi ki\tag{solve for $z$}$$
for some integer $k$.

---

Now why is the rule true?
$e^a = e^b$ is equivalent to $e^{b-a} = 1$ (multiply both sides by $e^{-b}$).

So the rule is really the same as $e^w= 1$ if and only if $w = 2\pi k i$ for some integer $k$.

To see why this is true, remember that for real $u$ and $v$, we have $e^{u + iv} = e^u(\cos v + i\sin v)$.

This is $1$ precisely when $e^u=1$ (so $u=0$) and $(\cos v,\sin v) = (1,0)$ (so $v = 2\pi k$).

In other words, when $u+iv = 0 + 2\pi k i$, as required.